# Control the size of inner circle of a radio button in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How to control the size of the inner dark circle of a radio button?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: you can hide the actual radio button and use css to create a "fake" radio button instead. There are plenty examples on how you do this, e.g. https://moderncss.dev/pure-css-custom-styled-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it by reducing the border width of the outer circle. The size of the inner circle is 50% percent of the size of the border width of the outer circle

ion-radio {
--border-width: 0.5px
}

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in a straightforward way. The radio button control is a feature of the browser used to read the page.

The way around this is to use some CSS tricks using `before` and `after` attributes of the button elements to effectively create a fake button, toggle or other similar control. You'll find lots of examples on the web if you search for something like "css style radio button" - like [this list](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/styling-radio-buttons/) of 59(!) different things people have done with colours, shapes and images.